# How to decrypt a PGP file within an Azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, gnupg, pgp

I use an azure function to transfer files from google to azure. The files I get are PGP encrypted and I need to decrypt them 'on the fly' before I encrypt them again with an Azure encryption.

In detail I have a string containing the PGP encrypted information and want to get another string where the data is no more encrypted. I tried to use Gnupg but it wants to have a home directory I cannot set up from the azure function.

here is a minimal example:

```
import gnupg
encrypted_string = '<encrypted_message...>'

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
pgp_passphrase = get_passphrase()

decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(data, passphrase=pgp_passphrase)

# *from here on I could use Azure encryption*
```

When I test it localy it works. In my Azure function the line starting with `gpg = gnupg.GPG()` returns the following error:

```
Exception: RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!
```

I see two options, but I could not figure out how to go for these.

1. set up a path in azure where Gnupg can do its stuff
2. Go for another lib or technique that does not need a local folder

If you have any idea on the topic, I am happy to hear about :-)

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the data with "your own encryption"? 99% of the time that's a bad idea since creating secure encryption is very difficult and it's just better to use well known and tested encryption.

Comment: @Challe, okay... bad wording... I do not want to use 'my own' encryption but an enctyption that is implemented within Azure :-)

Comment: Ok. Do you have PGP installed on the azure instance? @Pet

Comment: @Challe, I changed the misleading expressions in my question.
How should I install it within azure? I have the gnupg in my imports but I think thats it till now. How to 'install' PGP there?

Comment: The gnupg python module is just a python wrapper for the PGP software. You need to have PGP installed on the machine before you can use the wrapper. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/) is another wrapper with better [docs](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/)

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/orchestrator/standard-activities/pgp-encrypt-file?view=sc-orch-2019#install-gnupg) are microsoft docs on how to install gnupg on the machine

Comment: @Challe Pet is using Azure Functions ;) you cant just install software there. One way to solve it would be to run Azure Functions in a container. There you can add additional packages via apt-get

Comment: see here for an example: https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2019/06/25/customised-serverless-using-azure-functions-docker-and-kubernetes-event-driven-architecture-keda/

Comment: @silent thanks for clearing that out! Unfortunately I doubt there are any full python implementations that do GPG encryption/decryption so that seems to be the only possibility.

Comment: hello, thanks for clarification. I will check the resources you provided in the Link and see what I can do

Comment: @Pet did you solve your issue ? I'm having the same ...